# php-regex not compiling

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

When I run the below:

```
$MATH_REGEX = '/(?=(?<!\\)\$).(.+?)(?<!\\)\$/';
preg_replace_callback($MATH_REGEX, function ($match) {
        $latex_code = $match[0];
        return lx($latex_code); //lx is defined elsewhere
    }, "Test string $a=b$ .");
```

I get this:

```
$ php test.php
PHP Warning:  preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 26 in /home/sbird/public_html/faith/lib/view.php on line 26
```

What is wrong with my regex?

EDIT:

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May  4 2012 00:38:52) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Can you add the original (unescaped) regex in your question?

Comment: Have you tried not using an anonymous function?

Comment: @EdHeal what is wrong with anonymous functions?

Comment: @wroniasty - nothing - but sometimes useful to try without them in the first instance when you have a bug.

Comment: that's true, although in this case it was pretty obvious the error had nothing to do with the lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are escaping a `(`:

```
/(?=(?<!\\)\$).(.+?)(?<!\\)\$/
                 here:  ^^^
```

The resulting string passed to `preg_replace_callback` look like this:

```
php > $MATH_REGEX = '/(?=(?<!\\)\$).(.+?)(?<!\\)\$/';
php > echo $MATH_REGEX;
/(?=(?<!\)\$).(.+?)(?<!\)\$/
                       ^^ !!!
```

Comment: ahhh. This would be a classic kind of mistake. So apparently backslashes still need to be escaped is single-quoted strings...

Comment: Writing regexps in PHP is an endless source of errors like this. Perl/Python have it solved in a much better way.